# Binding not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm working on a quick & dirty WinForms application.  I have defined this class:

```
class NotifyingRectangle : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public int Left {
        get { return iLeft; }
        set {
            iLeft = value;
            onPropertyChanged( "Left" );
        }
    private int iLeft;

    // And so on for Top, Width & Height

    public event PropertyChangeEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public NotifyingRectangle( int left, int top, int width, int height ) {
        iLeft = left;
        iTop = top;
        iWidth = width;
        iHeight = height;
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string property ) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if ( handler != null )
            handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( property ) );
    }
}
```

In my Form, I declared a class instance variable:

```
private NotifyingRectangle plateRectangle;
```

Finally, I bind the class instance variable to 4 `NumericUpDown` controls:

```
nudLeft.DataBindings.Add( new Binding( "Value", plateRectangle, "Left", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged ) );
nudTop.DataBindings.Add( new Binding( "Value", plateRectangle, "Top", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged ) );
nudWidth.DataBindings.Add( new Binding( "Value", plateRectangle, "Width", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged ) );
nudHeight.DataBindings.Add( new Binding( "Value", plateRectangle, "Height", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged ) );
```

When the form is displayed, the `NumericUpDown` controls display the values in the properties of the class instance variable as I expect.  However, when I change the value of one of the controls by clicking on the up or down arrow, the value of the property does not seem to change. That is, I have created a `ValueChanged` event handler that's called by the 4 `NumericUpDown` controls and when I check the value of the properties of the class instance variable, the didn't change.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make these bindings work both ways?

Comment: Code works for me.  I created your rectangle with Left = 10, clicked on the NumBox a couple times, and checked the value of the rectangle, Left was now equal to 13.  Not sure what this `ValueChanged` event is, since you didn't document that.

Comment: `ValueChanged` is an event of the `NumericUpDown` control.

Comment: OK, but the posted code still works.